# Hive results not being saved into S3 bucket

Tags: hadoop, amazon-s3, hive, amazon-emr, hue

I am having trouble getting my Hive output to save to S3. I have tried `ssh`ing into the master node and running my command in Hive but it does not save the output. I have also tried running the command in Hue from the EMR console in AWS and still it does not save to S3. I also added the script as a step and still it doesn't save. The only way I have been able to get the results is to run it in Hue and then click to see results and download that way, then push them to S3. I am clueless as to why this is happening. Here is the query that I am running.

```
with temp as (
select /*+ streamtable(l) */ a.id, a.name, a.page
from my_table a
join my_other_table l on (a.id = l.id)
group by a.page, a.id, a.name)
insert overwrite directory 's3://bucket/folder/folder2/folder3/folder4/folder5/folder6/folder7/'
select page, count(distinct id) over (PARTITION BY page)
from temp
group by page;
```

As a note, I would prefer for the solution to work when adding a step since I plan to add `x` number of steps sequentially.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The normal way I've seen Amazon EMR output to Amazon S3 is to `CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE` with a `LOCATION` in Amazon S3.

For example:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS output_table
(gram string, year int, ratio double, increase double)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t'
STORED AS TEXTFILE
LOCATION 's3://my-bucket/directory';
```

Then, just `INSERT` data into that table:

```
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE output_table
SELECT gram FROM table...
```

Comment: that first snippet of code you provide creates a table in Hive from a location S3, that is correct and yes that is how I create tables from data in S3. I want to go from Hive ----> S3. As far as I know the query is prefixed by `insert overwrite directory` followed by the S3 bucket.

Comment: The above syntax works. You simply INSERT into the table, and it is written into S3.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution.

The problem was the trailing slash in the `S3` location, the base path of the directory you wish to over write should **NOT** contain a trailing slash.